# Windows -cp Mainclass could not be loaded

Tags: java, classpath, program-entry-point, cp

I want to add the mysql-connector to my classpath but it does not work with this:

```
@echo off
java -cp ../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;../lib/* de/KlickMich/LufthansaAG/test/Main -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -jar test.jar 
pause
```

It comes an Error that the Ma*inClass could not be found* or loaded..
Can anyone help me? How do I have to use the [-cp] option?
PS: The MainClass of my java project is de.KlickMich.LufthansaAG.test.Main

Comment: Post the exact and complete error message. And don't use the -jar and the -cp options together: they are mutually exclusive. -jar means: use the main class and classpath specified in the manifest of the jar file. -cp means: use this classpath and the main class specified as argument.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things wrong with your command line:

```
java -cp ../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;../lib/* de/KlickMich/LufthansaAG/test/Main -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -jar test.jar
```

First of all, you cannot use the `-cp` and `-jar` options together. The `-jar` option is used for running [executable jar files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/), and in that case the classpath is specified in the manifest of the jar file, and not on the command line with the `-cp` option.

If `test.jar` is an executable jar, then you specify the classpath and the main class in the manifest file inside the jar, and then you run it with a command like this:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -jar test.jar
```

Otherwise (if it is not an executable jar file), you have to put `test.jar` on the classpath, and specify the main class on the command line. In the line above you are specifying a main class the wrong way - do not use slashes (`de/KlickMich/LufthansaAG/test/Main`), but dots (`de.KlickMich.LufthansaAG.test.Main`). You have to specify a **class name** here, not a **file name**. So, it should be something like this:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -cp ../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;../lib/*;test.jar de.KlickMich.LufthansaAG.test.Main
```